# CSS transition is not working, it was working before

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

```
#front{
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-right:100px;
    transition:margin-left 1s;
    
    text-align:center;
     
    margin-bottom:-30px;  
  
}
```

The above code for transition was working before but after some time like 2-3 weeks later it stopped working. I don't know why?

I also have checked in different browsers but the transition is not working.

Comment: For a transition to happen there need to be two states. Here you are showing only one state, there should not be any transition. Please include all code necessary to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what result you want, but based on @gerad answer I just modified a bit. Change `transition` to `animation` and add `keyframes` if you want onload

```css
#front {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  animation: margin-left 1s;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

@keyframes margin-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="front">Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when you change the setting for `margin-left`. See an example below.

```css
#front {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  transition: margin-left 1s;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

#front:hover {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="front">Hello world</div>
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277923/are-your-code-works-fine-for-me-answers-acceptable

Comment: but i don't want to add the transition while hovering, I want the transition to show when the page opens.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks. Next time I'll put the code example in a comment.